# Android image fade animation

Tags: java, android, animation, android-studio, objectanimator

When I'd ran this code, it did nothing, I'm sure that this event is called when I touch the button. but It doesn't change the opacity of imageView.

```
View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        ObjectAnimator fadeAltAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(R.id.imgTest, "alpha", 0.2f);
        fadeAltAnim.start();
    }
};


findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: `onTouch()` captures many different touch events. Never do something like that and leave touch handling completely alone unless you know what you are doing. Use `OnClickListener` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code, its using ViewPropertyAnimator :

```
View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener()   {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    view.animate().alpha(0.2f).setDuration(1000);
    }
};
```

Its always good to set a duration, so the Animation knows how long its supposed to run.

EDIT : You might want to attach it to a MotionEvent if you are using onTouchListener , something like :

```
View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener()   {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(motionEvent == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        view.animate().alpha(0.2f).setDuration(1000);
    }
};
```

EDIT 2 :

If you want to use a Button its best to use an OnClickListener instead of onTouchListener, if you want to attach an Image you have to initiate it(for example in an ImageView) :

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgTest);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            imageView.animate().alpha(0.2f).setDuration(1000);

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I attach this to a button? it works when I touch the image, but I have a button, and I want the image to be fade, when I hit the button.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're passing in an id when the method requires the `View`. Try passing in the `View`.

So basically change `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(R.id.imgTest, "alpha", 0.2f);` to `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 0.2f);`

Here's an example

```
findViewById(R.id.image).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ObjectAnimator fadeAltAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "alpha", 0.2f);
            fadeAltAnim.start();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're using ObjectAnimator? Can you do:

```
AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(startAlphaValue, endAlphaValue);
anim.setDuration(duration);
view.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**try this** 

public class Animationtest extends Activity {

private ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    setAnimation();
}
private void setAnimation(){
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "touch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             ObjectAnimator fadeAltAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "alpha", 0.2f);
                fadeAltAnim.start();
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

}